# Algorithm to generate points of a circular polygon with N

Tags: circles, polygons

I'm programming a game and I want to create polygons that will act as the boundaries for this top-down game. I want to have circular boundaries like a hexagon, pentagon etc. which I can create as long as I have the locations (`x,y`) of each of the points in the shape/polygon.

I'd like to write some functions that can generate these locations given the number of sides (`N`) and the radius (`r`) of the shape. Almost exactly like how [this website does it](https://www.visnos.com/demos/polygon-explorer), except I just need to generate the point locations.

I don't know how to find this math-wise. Would it be aliasing the values of a circle to have `N` sides? I'm not too sure. Thank you :)

Comment: look up "root of unity"

Comment: The vertices are $\left(r\cos\frac{2\pi}n,r\sin\frac{2\pi}n\right)$

Comment: Thank you! The root of unity is exactly what I was looking for